# How to use objects within if statements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

At present I have a list of conditional statements such as:

```
if(x = 1) { $(#div).html('A') };

if(x = 2) { $(#div).html('B') };

if(x = 3) { $(#div).html('C') };

if(x = 4) { $(#div).html('D') };
```

This does the job but isn't very efficient.

I'm trying to take a DRY approach to this but am unsure of how to go about it.

I'm wondering if something similar to the following will work or if there's a better way to achieve this.

```
var arr = [
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D']
]

if ( x === arr[any of sub arrays][0]{ // 1, 2, 3 or 4

    $('div#').html('[triggered sub array[1]'); // if 1 is triggered, set html content to A, if 2, set html content to B and so on.    
}
```

Is there a term for what I'm trying to describe here so I can look it up?

Comment: `div#` seems like a syntax error, since it implies you're selecting a `<div>` coupled with a zero-length `id` property, and an `id` must be both unique and have a length of one, or more, characters.

Comment: I think it was probably just shorthand for "divId", another way of putting a "foobar" placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but...sounds like you could just use a map?

```
var map = {
  1: 'A',
  2: 'B',
  3: 'C'
};

if (map.hasOwnProperty(incomingNum)) {
  $('div#').html(map[incomingNum));
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed (I know the other comments are correct too, thanks guys!).  I'm quite new to arrays, maps & objects with JavaScript.

Comment: A map is just an object, we just call it a map because it serves a specific role in our minds.